# Как закрепить кнопку В КОРЗИНУ на карточке товара

Tags: woocommerce, корзина

В данный момент кнопка В КОРЗИНУ на карточках товаров всплывающая - появляется при наведении мышки на карточку товара. А нужно сделать ее стационарной. Чтобы была всегда, а не появлялась при наведении. Как это сделать? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Вот сайт: http://fitness-nutrition.by/aminokisloty/

Везде должна быть стационарной.

Спасибо.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Для начала нужно было отметить что это woocommerce
А так в свой css напишите:

```
.woocommerce ul.products li.product .button {
   opacity: 1;
   left: 0;
}
.woocommerce ul.products { 
   display: flex; 
   flex-direction: row; 
   flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Сработало) Может еще подскажите, как сделать карточки товаров одинаковой высоты? Сейчас они разной высоты, т.к. названия товаров разные. Выбрать максимальную высоту карточки в данный момент и сделать такими же по высоте все остальные. И еще, можно ли сделать, чтобы при добавлении в корзину не перегружалась страница? Возможно? Спасибо за помощь в любом случае.

Comment: Еще заметил только сейчас. С мобильного телефона кнопка КАТАЛОГ растянулась на всю ширину. А была короткой, как кнопка обычная. Это изменило всю мобильную версию. Фактически, мобильной версии теперь нет, а есть обычная пк версия , только на телефоне. Как поправить?

Comment: Тут смотрите какая ситуация Вам нужно перерисовать шаблон. Для одно высоты можно использовать js а можно просто fexbox. К примеру: .woocommerce ul.products {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;} Добавить корзину без перезагрузки это уже сложно нужны ajax запросы. По мобильной версии, у вас ее вообще нет. А так нужно смотреть это не от сделаных нами изменений. Там display: table и width 100%, так что так и должно быть.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы. Мобильной версии нет. Все правильно. Но сейчас нет. Она была. Это точно после внесения той строчки. Изменения каким-то образом повлияли и на кнопку каталог. Хотите уберу ту строчку? Посмотрите на мобильную версию... Там такая ситуация. Меняешь цвет шрифта, например, в одном месте - меняется везде!

Comment: Убрал строчку - мобильная версия не вернулась... как вернуть мобильную версию? что я мог сделать?

Comment: Деактивировал плагины, которые установил в последнее время. Не помогло. Единственное, важно ,что еще делал - добавил кусок кода в СSS, кажется, чтобы убрать КАТЕГОРИИ из url. Может это...

Comment: Мобильную версию вернул, добавить в хедер: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

Comment: :) Я не проверял весь сайт. А для одной высоты как я уже писал `display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;`

Comment: Куда конкретно это вставить? Нужна одинаковая высота для всех карточек товара

Comment: А еще, проверил сайт на PageSpeed Tools и выпал в осадок. Для мобильной версии было 90%. Для ПК ниже.  А сейчас скорости загрузки 40-50. Как это исправить? Удалить может плагин какой? из-за чего скорость загрузки могла так упасть? Спасибо)

Comment: Добавил в сам топик. По скорости нужно смотреть удаленно не скажешь.

Comment: Все равно не понял, куда ту строку добавить?)

Comment: В смысле? Это css свойства. У вас должен быть свой файл.

Comment: На счет высоты - нет, не сработало...

Comment: Я добавил скрин

Comment: Не получается... как тут скрин экрана вставить...

Comment: Добавил скрин наверху. Посмотрите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Они одной высоты, кнопка не прижалась, это нужно флекс бакс item нужно

Comment: Еще вопрос, если позволите. Вот главная: http://fitness-nutrition.by/ Надпись ХИТЫ ПРОДАЖ. Как эту надпись подвинуть выше к каталогу?

Comment: А еще вот карточка товара раскрытая. Пример: http://fitness-nutrition.by/bcaa-high-speed-130-g/ Как описание товара подвинуть выше к линии? Над этим описание есть слово ОПИСАНИЕ. Просто оно не нужно. Я сделал его белым цветов. Но оно есть. Его нужно убрать. И описание товара подвинуть выше к линии. Нужно, чтобы не исчезли при этом ХИТЫ ПРОДАЖ на главной. Спасибо)

Comment: По ближе подвинуть, у вас там пусто параграф.  Уберите его. Во втором случает там h2 в нем написано `"Описание"`

Comment: Где конкретно можно убрать "Описание"? Я знаю, что оно там есть. Только как убирается? И где подвинуть параграф? В каком именно файле?

Comment: Хороший вопрос скрипты у вас, я не могу знать что именно у вас формирует страницу.

Comment: Задал еще вопрос в группе по форме обратной связи. Можете глянуть? Или может Вам куда-нибудь переслать файл? Спасибо)

Comment: Добрый день. Помогите, пожалуйста, с еще одной загвоздкой) Вот сайт: ecomsoft.info. Посмотрите, пожалуйста, на главной странице примерно по середине раздел ABOUT US (лучше с пк смотреть). В кратком описании этого раздела на главной вставлен фоновый рисунок. Видите? А вот клон сайта: ecomsoft.ca. В этом же месте фонового рисунка нет. Через админку не могу вставить. Подскажите, как через код вставить в это место фоновый рисунок? Спасибо)

Comment: Сейчас там установлена белая картинка со ссылкой: background-image: url(https://ecomsoft.ca/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/White.jpeg); Как перепрописать ссылку на нужную картинку?

Comment: У меня и там и там картинка.

Comment: Это я добавил. Нашел, как это сделать через админку. А как через код не подскажите?

Comment: Я кода не вижу, чтобы что то сказать. Можно и просто css'ом

Comment: `#pg-2-1> .panel-row-style {
    background-image: url(https://ecomsoft.ca/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/180928021lc370a-2.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat;
}` вот тут он задан

Comment: Добрый день. Вносил коррективы в шаблон сайта: fitness-nutrition.by. В частности в шапке: Бренды-поиск-Впишите-Искать. Они сейчас расположены не в одну строчку. А должны быть в одной строке друг за другом. Подкажите, как расположить их в одной строке? Что я сделал не так? Спасибо.